# Filtering multiple aggregated columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have a database with sales, I had to group sales by day of week so that each day has it's own column  for the selected months. I need to filter out the aggregated sum for a day where there were no sales (the result would still be NULL), I did add the s.Amount_sold>0 in the where clause but I'm not sure if that's the correct solution to the problem. I've been trying to think of a way other than just repeating all of the sums in the where / having clause but no luck so far, would really appreciate some help.

```
SELECT
t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME AS SALES_MONTH,
UPPER(LEFT(p.PROD_NAME,CHARINDEX('&',p.PROD_NAME)-1))+' '+ SUBSTRING(p.PROD_NAME,CHARINDEX('&',p.PROD_NAME),LEN(p.PROD_NAME))+' ('+CAST(p.PROD_ID AS VARCHAR)+')' AS PRODUCT_NAME,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=1) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Monday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=2) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Tuesday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=3) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Wednesday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=4) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Thursday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=5) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Friday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=6) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Saturday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=7) THEN s.AMOUNT_SOLD END) AS Sunday
FROM sh.CUSTOMERS c
JOIN sh.SALES s ON c.CUST_ID=s.CUST_ID
JOIN sh.TIMES t ON s.TIME_ID=t.TIME_ID
JOIN sh.PRODUCTS p ON s.PROD_ID=p.PROD_ID
  WHERE s.PROD_ID = 5 
  AND (t.CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER=2 AND t.CALENDAR_YEAR=2000) AND s.AMOUNT_SOLD>0
GROUP BY  p.PROD_NAME,t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME,t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER,p.PROD_ID
ORDER BY t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER
```

Comment: some sample data and the expected result will help us understand your question better

Comment: What do YOU mean by "I need to filter out the aggregated sum for a day where there were no sales"?  SQL queries have a fixed set of columns.  If you want a variable number of columns, then you need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

`SUM(CASE WHEN (t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK=1) THEN IFNULL(s.AMOUNT_SOLD, 0) END) AS Monday`